# JSoup Selector for multiple tags containing a phrase

Tags: css-selectors, jsoup

In JSoup, how do I write a selector that matches an element that can be from multiple tags, and contains a text phrase?

For example, I want to match any header tag that contains "phrase".

This works, but I want to avoid repetition:
`:has(h1:contains(phrase), h2:contains(phrase), h3:contains(phrase))`

This only matches `h3`'s containing the phrase:
`:has(h1, h2, h3:contains(phrase))`

---

Sorry I didn't specify earlier because I wanted to keep the question simple. :( I need a pure selector solution as I'm actually using `jsoup` https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax which "supports a CSS (or jquery) like selector syntax to find matching elements".

Comment: Do you need a pure selector solution or can you use `filter()`, it would help if you post a more complete example of the code you have. As it stands right now it seems like `$( "h1,h2,h3" ).filter( ":contains(phrase)" )` should work.

Comment: Here's a fiddle I was working on that includes Raul's `.filter` solution and some other stuff that may or may not help. https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/av930L4r/

Comment: Thanks guys for the ideas so far. Sorry I didn't specify earlier, I do need a pure selector solution as I'm actually using jsoup https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax which "supports a CSS (or jquery) like selector syntax to find matching elements". @RaulSauco

Comment: @Zephyr I wish jQuery had that `:containsOwn` selector that jsoup does, it would be very useful at times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSoup supports the `select(String query)` method not only on objects of type `Document`, but also on objects of type `Elements`. `select(String query)` itself returns `Elements`. Therefore you may concatenate several select statements to filter out what you want:

```
Elements hWithText = doc.select("h1,h2,h2").select(":matchesOwn(regEx)");
```

Of course you can also use `select(":contains(whatever)"`, if you do not need the flexibility of regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using the `filter()` method.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("h1,h2,h3").filter(":contains('key word')").addClass('bingo');
});
```

```css
.bingo {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <h1 class="not-it">This header does not contain the phrase</h1>
  <h2 class="not-it">This header does not contain the phrase</h2>
  <h3 class="not-it">This header does not contain the phrase</h3>
  <h1 class="it">This header contains the key word</h1>
  <h2 class="it">This header contains the key word</h2>
  <h3 class="it">This header contains the key word</h3>
  <h4 class="it">This header contains the key word but is an H4</h4>
</div>
```